# Values flask template not parsing

Tags: python, flask

So, I have created a flask template from where I can upload multiple files. Each file type has its own submit button, and depending on which button is clicked, I want a different piece of Python code to run.

The first half of my Flask template looks as follows:

```
<h3> Upload Portfolio Data</h3>
<form action="{{ url_for('admin') }}" method="post" enctype=multipart/form-data>
<fieldset>
    <label class="control-label">Select Portfolio Upload File</label>
    <input id="input-1" type="file" class="file" name="portfolios">
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value = "portfolios">Upload</button>
    </div>
    <h3>Upload Security Lists</h3>
    <label class="control-label">Select Security Upload File</label>
    <input id="input-1" type="file" class="file" name="securities">
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value = "securities">Upload</button>
    </div>
     <table class="table" style="width:100%">
    <tr> 
         <th>Priority </th>
         <th>Target </th>
     </tr>
    <tr>
    <h2>Transaction Priority</h2>
        <td>1st</td>
        <td>
            <select class="form-control" name="first" style="float:left; width:150px">
               <option value="asset_allocation">Asset Allocation</option>
               <option value="sector">Sector</option>
               <option value="region">Region</option>
               <option value="security_opinion">Security Neutral</option>
               <option value="security_nr">Security NR</option>
          </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2nd</td>
        <td>
            <select class="form-control" name="second" style="float:left; width:150px">
               <option value="asset_allocation">Asset Allocation</option>
               <option value="sector" selected ="selected">Sector</option>
               <option value="region">Region</option>
               <option value="security_opinion">Security Neutral</option>
               <option value="security_nr">Security NR</option>
          </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

In Python, I then try to read the values of the buttons as follows:

```
if request.method == "POST":

    if 'portfolios' in request.form.values():
        # do something

    if 'securities' in request.form.values():
        # do something
```

But somehow, the values of the button are not passed through to the request.form.values() function. If I print the request.form then it has values from elsewhere in my form, but not the values of the buttons:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('second', 'sector'), ('first', 'asset_allocation'), ('fifth', 'security_nr'), ('third', 'region'), ('fourth', 'security_opinion')])
```

Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: by using the dict method `values()`, do you mean that the input is sure to have a value containing "portfolio" or "securities"? I guess these words to be in `keys()`.

Comment: Can you just print request.form to check what's inside?

Comment: @Leonard2: I attach the value to the button (see flask template), so I would assume it shows up? If I change to request.form.keys() the problem remains :(
@ lapinkoira: I added the print info in the post

Answer (score 0):

`request.form` is a dictionary-like object. The `values()` method of a dict gives you, well, the values. But "portfolios" and "securities" are the *keys*, not the values. Just use:

```
if 'portfolios' in request.form:
```

etc, since `in` looks at the keys.

Comment: Hmmm, but they dont seem to be passed at all. The issue seems to be in the Flask template rather than the Python code?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Funny, been looking at this for days, then decide to post the question here and then I see it myself... Anyway, it seems I didnt pass a name with the button, which resulted in the value also not being passed....